# smallest $k$ s.t. $(x+y)^2\leq k(x^2-xy+y^2)$

Tags: inequality

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

Q: Find $K$?

$$(x+y)^2\leq k(x^2-xy+y^2)$$.

where $\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: What do you mean 'Find $K$'? I guess you want the least $K$ such that the inequality holds.

Comment: I suppose you are asking for the least $k$ such that the statement is true

Answer (score 3):

You can write the inequality as
$$
(k-1)x^2-(2+k)xy+(k-1)y^2\ge0
$$
and this should hold for every pair $(x,y)$, which means that the discriminant of the polynomial
$$
(k-1)t^2-(2+k)t+(k-1)
$$
must be nonpositive and $k-1>0$. For the discriminant we have
$$
(2+k)^2-4(k-1)^2\le0
$$
which becomes
$$
-3k^2+12k\le0
$$
or
$$
k^2-4k\ge0
$$
that is, $k\le 0$ or $k\ge4$. Taking into account $k>1$, we conclude $k\ge4$. So $4$ is the least value for which the inequality holds on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 2):

This is part of a general method to study positivity of *quadratic forms* (sums of terms of degree $2$ in the variables, any number of variables). First I will solve you problem using it and then I will talk a little about the problem in general.

**This particular problem:**

This
$$0\leq(k-1)x^2+(-k-2)xy+(k-1)y^2$$

we can write it as $$(k-1)\left[\left(x^2+\frac{(-k-2)}{(k-1)}xy+\frac{(-k-2)^2y^2}{4(k-1)^2}\right)+(1-\frac{(-k-2)^2}{4(k-1)^2})y^2\right],$$

i.e.

$$(k-1)\left[\left(x+\frac{-k-2}{2(k-1)}y\right)^2+(1-\frac{(-k-2)^2}{4(k-1)^2})y^2\right].$$

We need the positivity of the coefficient of $y^2$.

Therefore $$1\geq\frac{(-k-2)^2}{4(k-1)^2}.$$ From where $$4(k-1)^2\geq(k+2)^2,$$ 
i.e.
$$k(3k-12)\geq0.$$

This gives us $k\leq0$ or $k\geq4$.

The positivity of the coefficient $(k-1)$ gives us $k\geq1$. Intersecting we get $k\geq4$.

**In general:**

To study the positivity of a quadratic form (this was a quadratic form). You can always bring it to the form $\sum \alpha_iZ_i^2$ for some coefficients $\alpha_i$ and new variables $Z_i$. The form will be positive iff all the coefficients are $\geq0$. There is an algorithm for reducing a quadratic form to this *diagonal form*. To not explain it in all detail, let me say that it just consists in *completing the squares* successively for each variable, and when there is only the term $xy$ for some variable $x$ and no $x^2$ you make the substitution $x=Z_1+Z_2$ and $y=Z_1-Z_2$.

From this diagonalization process we get a way to test positivity directly from the coefficients of the original form without having to reduce to the canonical form, see Sylvester's criterion.

Answer (score 1):

$$(x+y)^2\leq k(x^2-xy+y^2)\iff (k-1)x^2-(2+k)xy+(k-1)y^2\geq0$$

using the inequality
$$xy\leq \frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)$$
we have

$$(k-1)x^2-(2+k)xy+(k-1)y^2\geq (k-1)x^2-\frac{2+k}{2}(x^2+y^2)+(k-1)y^2\\
=(\frac{k}{2}-2)(x^2+y^2)\geq 0\iff k\geq 4$$

and if we take $x=y=1$ we find that $4\leq k$.

So  $k= 4$ answers the question.

Comment: But is $4$ the smallest one which works?

Comment: Yes $k=4$ is optimal and to see this take $x=y=1$.

Comment: I know, but that is missing from your answer ;)

Comment: Sorry I don't see the word smallest in the title:)

Answer (score 1):

Insert $x=y=1$ to obtain $k\geq 4$. 
If $k\geq 4$, then $\frac{k+2}{k-1}\leq 2$ and $k-1\geq1$, so:
$$k(x^2-xy+y^2)-(x+y)^2 = (k-1)\left(x^2-\frac{k+2}{k-1}xy+y^2\right)
\geq x^2-2xy+y^2
= (x-y)^2\geq 0$$